# Tabs inside tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I have a TabActivity.
In one of the TAB I want to create (inside the tabbed activity) 2 tabs as well.
I want to use simple buttons for changing the inner tabs.
Will be like

```
----------------------------------
       Button1      Button2
  ------------------------------
  |                            |
  |                            |
  |                            |
  |   Here chage the activity  |
  |                            |
  |                            |
  |                            |
  |                            |
  |                            |
  |                            |
  |                            |
  ------------------------------

TAB1 | TAB2 | ....      | TABN |
---------------------------------
```

The inner activities are : 1 is simple layout, the otherone is list activity.

Maybe I need to create like a frame inside and remove/inflate the related views? But if the container is ListActivity - won't it create a problem if no listview in inflated?

Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

One of the first really bad UI designs I did involved tabs inside a tab--it's a horrible thing, really makes a mess of the GUI, (You know, dogs and cats living together, users screaming in pain, ...)

I suggest you come up with another system.

Comment: I have 3 tabs. 1 of the Tab is a favourite tab. but I have 2 kinds of favourites- uosers and books. I want to have 2 different layouts/ativities for. Don't you think both should be under favourtie?

Comment: Could be, or you could have "Favorite Users" and "Favorite Books" tabs.  You could even have a single "Favorite" tab and slide to switch between users and books.  It's actually having multiple tab rows that seems to cause UI confusion.

Comment: Hmmmmmm so you recommend to slide the activity to open a new one? will sliding between them keep the all data - re-inflate everything? How can do the sliding